# install newest version of ONE private library in a requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, pip

I can run `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`, and I can set a packagename to something like `package>=0.42`, but is there a way to say "always attempt to upgrade this one package"? The problem with `--upgrade` on the entire file is it tries to upgrade all packages.

I tried adding --upgrade on a line in the txt file and it gets rejected. [This seems pretty close to what I need](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/17) and isn't implemented.

It's a local (private) package that is being included with `--extra-index-url`, so.. maybe there's a workaround in that index, like only listing the most current package version in the index?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `--upgrade` flag can be currently specified on a package level inside the `requirements` file.

One workaround would be to have a *separate requirements file* for these kind of packages.

<sup>There is also that [`--force-reinstall`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=#cmdoption--force-reinstall) option that you may try using.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to remove the version pinning for the package, each time the requirements file is run - the latest version will be installed.